# Probability of darts landing an specified areas

Tags: probability

I have a homework question that contains multiple parts, I have been able to solve part a-c, however I am unsure of how to do part d.

The question reads:

> Suppose you throw a dart at a circular target of radius $10$ inches.
>   Assuming that you hit the target and that the coordinates of the
>   outcomes are chosen at random, what is the probability that the dart
>   falls
>
> (d) within the first quadrant and within $2$ inches of the rim.

My thoughts:

part b asked what is the probability that it is within $2$ inches of the rim, which I found to be $1- \dfrac{\pi 64}{\pi 100} = \dfrac{36}{100}$.

part c asked what is the probability that it hits within the first quadrant of the target. which I found to be $\dfrac{1}{4}$.

Now, my thoughts for part d is to simple multiple these two together, because it is asking for the intersection.

So would the answer be $\dfrac{1}{4} \left(1-\dfrac{\pi 64}{ \pi 100}\right)$?

Comment: What do you mean by "pi 64/pi 100"?  Is that anything like 16/25?

Comment: Your answers would be more readable with MathJax, and they can be simplified considerably, but they look correct. Multiplication is justified by independence of angle and distance from the centre.

Comment: You're assuming the dart's landing spot is distributed uniformly over the area of the dartboard. I think that's what the problem intended, but it's a completely unrealistic assumption in real life (unless you're standing so far from the dart board that you have almost no chance of hitting it at all, in which case I think the few hits you did get would be approximately uniformly distributed). If this were my homework I would be very tempted to paste a printout of the question and intended solution onto a 10-inch-radius paper circle, throw a dart at the circle many times, and submit that.

Comment: We don't turn in homework, grade is based solely on Exams, but I like the way you think

Comment: Multiplying is somewhat hazardous. In this case, landing within $2$ of the rim and landing in the first quadrant happen to be independent, so multiplication will give the right answer.  But in other roughly similar sounding situations, independence might fail. The area computation, by contrast, is safe.

Answer (score 2):

So here are lots of details.

To get the area of the two inch rim, we want 
$$A = \pi(10)^2-\pi(10-2)^2 = \pi36.$$
But we are only interested in the section that is in the first quadrant, which is $$\frac{1}{4}A = \pi9.$$

So the probability of interest is
$$\frac{\pi9}{\pi100} = \frac{9}{100}.$$

---

If you wanted to try to use complements, then if $R = \{\text{Hit 2 inch rim in Q1}\}$
and $\bar R = \{\text{Miss Q1 rim }\}$, then
\begin{align*}
P(R) &= 1-P(\bar R) \\
&=1-[P(\text{Hit quadrants 2,3,4})+P(\text{Miss rim in Q1 })]\\
&= 1-\left(\frac{3}{4}\left(\frac{\pi100}{\pi100}\right)+\frac{3}{4}\left(\frac{\pi(10-2)^2}{\pi(10)^2}\right)\right) \\
&=1-\frac{91}{100} \\
&= \frac{9}{100}.
\end{align*}

Comment: This now agrees with OP's solution

Answer (score 0):

In a theoretical sense, yes you would multiply the two values you got as it's a X AND Y probability. It obviously won't be as simple to do this for a real-life scenario.